# SQL server linked server to SAS(Statistical Analysis System)?

Tags: sql-server, sas, odbc, driver, linked-server

has anyone ever been able to create a sql server linked server to SAS?

I have created an ODBC connection (32bit) to SAS

[image]

This ODBC works for e.g. **QlikView**, **Tableau** etc.. but how would  set it up for SQL server?

[image]

1. **Provider**?
2. **Product name**?
3. **Data Source**?
4. **Location**?
5. **Catalog**?

Comment: Normally people would link the other way around.  That is they would use SAS to do their statistical analysis by reading (and possibly writing) data from their external DBMS.  Trying to get the DBMS to read from their statistical analysis files as if they were an actual DBMS is probably harder.  Does SQL Server support reading from generic ODBC drivers? or does it require OLE compatible drivers?

Answer (score 0):

If the DSN is already created, you can access it in SAS directly using:

```
libname myServer odbc dsn=PROD_PL0000 schema='dbo';
```

Then you'll see it as a SAS library that you can work with natively. If you do it via the GUI you can check a box to have it reconnect at start up.

Comment: Hi, i'm not really following? I dont want SAS to access SQL server I want to be able to create a linked server from SQL server OR maybe write a direct t-sql query to access SAS library via SQL server

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. The problem is in the SAS provider for OLE DB connections, it can't create a popular instance with SAS tables.

To create the linked server via OLE DB you need to go to the SAS website, download the files and install on the SQL server to set up the connection.

https://support.sas.com/downloads/package.htm?pid=648

Comment: We got this to work. The first thing you need to do is to configure an ODBC driver to SAS SPD server and not to SAS. When the ODBC is setup you can easily just create a linked server ( microsoft ole db provider for odbc drivers) and just typ in you DSN name in the Data source filed of your linked server